# Does using gerrit/jenkins with a single Git repository for multiple projects work?

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, gerrit

We currently have a large SVN repository with multiple projects including a lot of shared libraries which are heavily relied on by most of the software we write.

At the moment, we use git on our local machines and email patch files back and forth. When we agree a patch is ready it's committed back to SVN. Jenkins detects which projects the code changes affect, check out the relevant bits of the repository and runs the appropriate unit tests. This works but is a bit clunky and separates the review process from the codebase.

I've been reading up on gerrit which sounds quite promising but the one thing I've not been able to get a good feel for is whether there's a good workflow we could adopt using git, Jenkins and gerrit if we have a single repository containing multiple projects?

Comment: What problems do you expect? Give it a try. Do you know the [life-of-a-patch](https://source.android.com/source/life-of-a-patch.html)? You're aware of the [Gerrit Trigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) plugin for Jenkins?

Comment: When I've looked at these sorts of tools before, the documentation has indicated that we need a single repository per project. I couldn't see from the gerrit docs whether or not having all our projects in one repository is something that is supported.

Comment: I've not seen the life-of-a-patch flow-chart before but we use a similar (more manual) process at the moment.

Comment: What prohibits you from using a single repo? I mean, probably one-repo-per-project would have advantages also for you, but what should go wrong when you keep that at least for the beginning?

Comment: Are you saying multiple gerrit projects can point to a single git repository? I got the impression that if I did that then a change to one project would result in multiple projects indicating a review was required?

Comment: No that would be one project only.

Comment: Okay, so the answer to my question then is "No, you must divide your monolithic repository up into separate projects" ?

Comment: When you need separate permissions for different paths, then yes.